# Disable udev renaming for Android USB tethering using randon MACs

Tags: udev

I have 4G failover via an old Android phone plugged in to USB.

This was working find as interface `usb0`.

Since upgrading to Debian 12 the device gets renamed to something completely random, and different every time it is plugged in. This fucks up `/etc/network/interfaces` and my `iptables` script.

```
# grep -a renamed  /var/log/syslog
2023-06-27T11:30:09.891759+01:00 calleva kernel: [    1.117331] r8169 0000:02:00.0 enp2s0: renamed from eth0
2023-06-27T11:30:09.891773+01:00 calleva kernel: [    1.144188] r8169 0000:03:00.0 enp3s0: renamed from eth1
2023-06-27T11:30:09.891903+01:00 calleva kernel: [    2.997299] rndis_host 2-1.6:1.0 enx720b8e586e43: renamed from usb0
2023-06-27T11:30:09.892058+01:00 calleva kernel: [    5.010330] rt2800pci 0000:01:00.0 wlp1s0: renamed from wlan0
2023-06-27T11:30:09.892071+01:00 calleva kernel: [    5.325336] rtl8192cu 1-1.4:1.0 wlx08beac0a6c1d: renamed from wlan0
2023-06-27T12:27:13.975350+01:00 calleva kernel: [ 3429.810797] rndis_host 2-1.6:1.0 enx9657a45d9349: renamed from usb0
2023-06-29T22:24:16.219329+01:00 calleva kernel: [212048.668218] rndis_host 2-1.6:1.0 enx5edf49046a6d: renamed from usb0
2023-06-29T22:27:16.975407+01:00 calleva kernel: [212229.420430] rndis_host 2-1.6:1.0 enxea7010e4b5e5: renamed from usb0
2023-06-29T22:53:13.186625+01:00 calleva kernel: [213785.614002] rndis_host 2-1.6:1.0 enx76f12e43a7a6: renamed from usb0
```

I believe that there are two problems

- something called `udev` is renaming things, and
- the Android phone is generating random MACs becauase 'security' bollocks.

There are no settings available on the phone. Therefore: how can this `udev` nonsense be stopped?

While I'm at it: I noticed that, after editing `/etc/network/interfaces` and `ifup` the interface goes to `UNKNOWN` rather than `UP`. What's going on?!

```
enx76f12e43a7a6: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc fq_codel state UNKNOWN group default qlen 1000
```

Tried adding

```
SUBSYSTEM=="net", ACTION=="add", ATTRS{product}=="XT1700", NAME="hp"
```

to a new file in `/etc/udev/rules.d

Answer (score 2):

Moved the file containing

```
SUBSYSTEM=="net", ACTION=="add", ATTRS{product}=="XT1700", NAME="hp"
```

from `/etc/udev/rules.d/hp` to `/etc/udev/rules.d/99-persistent-net.rules`.
(I suspect that if the file has a 'wrong' name then it doesn't work -- fuck knows.)

Ran

```
# udevadm control --reload-rules
# udevadm trigger
```

and re-plugged the device and now the interface is called `hp` and this seems to be stable.